# Delphi's ribbon glitchy images

Tags: delphi, icons, ribbon

I am trying to use the ribbon control in delphi, but I'm having problems with the icons. I have one ImageList (16x16 - apparently higher resolutions are bad - the ribbon malfunctions) and I want to use it for ribbon icons. But this problem keeps happenning:

When I have the "Large icons" checkbox unchecked, the small buttons (Action2) are fine. But the bigger one is not.
[image]
On the other hand, when I tick the checkbox, this happens:
[image]

How do I setup the ribbon correctly? This is crazy :/

Comment: Please crop your screen shots in the future to only show the applicable portion. It allows them to display at a larger size, which makes them more readable/visually clear. In this case, you could have shifted the Action Editor dialog toward the left edge, and cropped it to about half the width of that dialog and from the top edge of the ribbon to the area just below the Large Icons checkbox. This would have made the image much clearer to see. :)

Comment: Will do. Sorry. I also figured a solution, will add an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, well, I figured it out. In order to use both image types, one has to have two separate ImageLists - each one holding different icons dimensions. The ActionManager has more fields for Images, which I didn't notice first - `Images`, `DisabledImages`, `LargeImages`(that's it!) and `LargeDisabledImages`. So in order to have the full functionality of the Ribbon, you have to keep 4 ImageLists.

*(I am keeping the answer here for future reference)*

Comment: If it is the answer then [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it).

Comment: I have to wait two days (the system says so)